How to get type of object keys as readonly array in TypeScript?
What is needed:
type Data = {
  user: User
  bank: Bank
}

// this type should be a readonly array ['user', 'bank']
type Keys = keysof Data

// compiler should show error here as it should be exactly ['user', 'bank']
const keys: Keys = ['user', 'user']

This is not working as expected:
type BadKeys = (keyof Data)[]

const keys: BadKeys = ['user', 'user'] // no error here
const keys: BadKeys = []               // no error here


You can make it readonly with readonly (keyof Data)[], but that still doesn't require either 1. all keyof Data to be in the array; or 2. each keyof Data to only be in the array once.

To the extent you can do this, you should not. keyof isn't known to be in any particular order, unions aren't iterable in any user-known order, the return value of Object.keys() can have all kinds of extra stuff in it. See linked q/a above for more info.

@jcalz I have neither Object.keys, nor unions in my examples, so its ok. But thanks for linking q/a.

keyof is a union.
